# Is there any potential issue removing this ISNULL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

Recently we uncovered a long running proc and one of my colleagues pointed out that that dropping the ISNULL in the where clause sped things up for reasons pointed out in this post [Is there is any Performance issue while using ISNULL() in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924913/is-there-is-any-performance-issue-while-using-isnull-in-sql-server). I did some Google searching but couldn't find out for sure if there was any danger in missing data. I know if you say something like this

```
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MemberID FROM Person WHERE MemberId IS NOT Null)
```

and MemberId is nullable you won't get any matches if you don't include the "IS NOT NULL" but I think that is a different issue? Maybe not?

Here is the change my coworker is proposing.

```
where ISNULL(ct.DisabilityBenefitsConnectAuthorized,0) = 1
```

Would become

```
where ct.DisabilityBenefitsConnectAuthorized = 1
```

It doesn't seem to be effecting results however I am not 100% sure that it couldn't and we just don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**why not just try it out yourself with a simplified example**, like:

```
declare @x bit

--@x is currently null
if isnull(@x,0)=1 begin print 'is one!' end else begin print 'not one!' end
if @x=1 begin print 'is one!' end else begin print 'not one!' end

set @x=0
if isnull(@x,0)=1 begin print 'is one!' end else begin print 'not one!' end
if @x=1 begin print 'is one!' end else begin print 'not one!' end

set @x=1
if isnull(@x,0)=1 begin print 'is one!' end else begin print 'not one!' end
if @x=1 begin print 'is one!' end else begin print 'not one!' end
```

OUTPUT:

```
not one!
not one!
not one!
not one!
is one!
is one!
```

based on the above, it looks like you can remove the ISNULL()

Comment: Yup, empirical methods have their value too.

Comment: Because I wasn't clever enough to come up with this nifty test! Fortunately you where and it indeed proves that there is no issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That change will be fine.

Neither `NULL` or `0` equate to `1`, therefore the results will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> MemberId is nullable you won't get any matches if you don't include
>   the "IS NOT NULL" but I think that is a different issue? Maybe not?

No it is not. You have to test for nullable `MemberID` values in the `WHERE` clause of the inner query. You won't get any values if there is any `NULL` values `MemberID` in the `Person` table. May be it would be better if you use `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE leftids IS NULL` instead of the `IN` predicate, it is safer.