# What is the performance impact with using IS NULL OR vs. ISNULL with LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a parameterised query where there is a requirement for the `LIKE` clause to include `NULL` values when `field LIKE '%'`.

I have multiple solutions; I ran these queries side-by-side and they return the similar execution plans with the same summary and the query times are similar. I worry about how these queries scale-up in performance for tables with millions of records.

```
-- Where @PartId is typically '%' or could be 'Part123%'.
SELECT *
FROM dbo.OrderItems AS oi
WHERE oi.PartId IS NULL OR oi.PartId LIKE @PartId

SELECT *
FROM dbo.OrderItems AS oi
WHERE ISNULL(oi.PartId, '') LIKE @PartId

SELECT *
FROM dbo.OrderItems AS oi
WHERE COALESCE(oi.PartId, '') LIKE @PartId
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924913/is-there-is-any-performance-issue-while-using-isnull-in-sql-server) suggests that there is very little difference between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE`. Grant Fritchey demonstrates in this [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/) that applying functions on `WHERE` clauses causes a bigger performance hindrance than using `LIKE`, however I've read that using logical `OR` can cause performance issues in queries. What is the performance impact with using `IS NULL OR` vs. the alternative of `ISNULL`?

Edit: This is the execution plan summary for the queries:
[image]

Comment: I think the first query doesn't work as desired, as it retursn rows with null value witrhout looking at @CustomerName

Comment: Surely the plans are the same, as you say with every query 'give me all you have'

Comment: @Turo I described using `'%'` to include `NULL` values. I've removed `@CustomerName` to clarify my question.

Comment: Those aren't the execution plans, they are just a summary of the plans. Right-click and hit Show XML to see the real plans. By comparing the XML you will discover whether or not they are actually doing the same thing or if they just happen to have the same summary.

Comment: The logic of your search impacts performance. It is a dumb scan with no chance for anything else to happen. Because of particular data model and search logic. Playing with "ISNULL" under given conditions gives not more effect than changing T-short.

Comment: Are there any indexes on the table?  Try adding one on the Name column.

Comment: @MJH I've added a more concrete example on a much bigger table with indexes.

Comment: @JonathanAllen thanks for the correction. The real plans are not completely identical upon inspection.

Comment: Catch-All queries like this are better handled with dynamic sql.  https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: You might also get some extra insights by adding a SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON; and then passing in a few different parameter options to all three queries.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't paste the plan that was chosen, but I can only assume that it involved a table scan?

Instead of using "WHERE CONDITION1 OR CONDITION2" it is sometimes worth rewriting your SQL to use a union query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customers AS c
WHERE c.Name IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customers AS c
WHERE c.Name = @CustomerName
```

This **can** prevent the table scan.

Comment: I have added the execution plan to the question - and it was a Table Scan.

Comment: I just edited my answer to remove the unnecessary LIKE keyword (replaced with "=")

Comment: This includes `NULL` records when the parameter is not `'%'`. What if the value is `'Bob%'`?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your query logic. Your where clause

```
oi.PartId IS NULL OR oi.PartId LIKE '%'
```

and other two where clauses just **literally** means "select me records where PartID is null **or** PartID is **NOT** null".

Since PartID can only be NULL or not null, why do you need the where clause in the first place?

Comment: Because `'%'` would be parameterised. Other values could be supplied to the query e.g. `'AB123%'` and would not include `NULL`s.

Answer (score 0):

You tested?  Testing to only `like '%'` is flawed results.  If you replace `like` with `=` it is still flawed.

These queries return different results!

```
declare @match varchar(10)  = '%match%';
declare @val varchar(10) = null;

select 'yes' 
where @val is null or @val like @match;

select 'yes'
where isnull(@val, '') like @match;
```